# Status message "Thank you. Your information has been saved." is missing on profile submit

Tags: wordpress, profile, status, missing

I'm currently testing our recent upgrade from 4.7.19 to 4.7.29 on our test server.  We have a public email list signup page on our website using a civicrm profile with a re-direct to a new (empty) email list signup page.  On our live site under the old release, when someone completes and submits this page, they get the message "Thank you. Your information has been saved." along with the fresh page.  But under the new release we don't get that status message displayed.  If I take out the re-direct I'll get that message but I don't like that generated page with the inappropriate ">>Back to Listings" link.

Is there a (non-programming) way for me to get that message displayed again as it was under the old release, or is this an inadvertant bug?  Thanks for your help.

Wordpress 4.9.1

Comment: Check for any JS error on the page. Also can check if you can replicate it on http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: Pradeep, you are right, there was a javascript error, and when I tried it again today it worked just fine.  Sorry for wasting your time :-(

Comment: Thought of posting as an answer so that you can close this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

There might be JS error which is causing status message not to appear. Please check for any JS error on browser console. i feel some wp plugin might be conflicting with CiviCRM plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There was indeed a javascript error when I had the problem. When I tested this again a day later I did in fact get the expected status message (without my having implemented any fix).