# profile submission has no confirmation message

Tags: profile

civi 5.52 wordpress 6
I'm not getting message "Thank you. Your information has been saved." after profile submitted.
It just shows completed profile.
Data is successfully saved

this [previous query](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22055/status-message-thank-you-your-information-has-been-saved-is-missing-on-profi?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C20.4069) suggests javascript error so I include image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript problem - the question is what is causing it.  It could be caused by CiviCRM but unless others are reporting the same thing, that's unlikely.  Otherwise, it might be a conflict with another plugin on your site.  If you're not using a default WP theme, try switching to that and see if the problem continues.  Failing that, see what other plugins are adding javascript on your site and disable those to isolate the problem.